# Using private and protected methods in one controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, private, protected

All the articles say about the difference between private and protected methods, however there's no clearance about using it.

So if  code something like:

```
private
  def my_method
    #some code
  end
```

Does private affect only the my_method or everything below?

**UPDATE:** 
And if affects everything what if I want to use protected methods as well?
If I code below my_method:

```
protected
  def another_method
    #some code
  end
```

Does it mean that private method has ended and protected methods section has started?

Comment: everything below.

Comment: "Does it mean that private method has ended and protected methods section has started?" - yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simply answer your question: yes, when you have the following code:

```
private
  ....

protected
  ....
```

Then private stops where protected begins.